# NTLM in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, ntlm, ntlm-authentication

I want to access a link that is protected with username and password through a windows authentication popup.

I read that this requires an NTLM plugin for Cypress. I want to access a form link https://etc.domain.com/dirlisting/notifications and here I want to login:

```
 it('loginpopup', () => {
    cy.ntlm(["https://etc.domain.com/dirlisting/notifications"], "Administrator", "password");
    cy.visit("https://etc.domain.com/dirlisting/notifications");
  })
```

I tried this code but received the following error: "Invalid host [https://etc.domain.com/dirlisting/notifications] in ntlmHosts, must be one of: 1) a hostname or FQDN, wildcards accepted. 2) hostname or FQDN with port, wildcards not accepted (localhost:8080 or [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or *.acme.com are ok, https://www.google.com:443/search is not ok).

I tried also it without https.

I tried `cy.visit('https://username:password@www.xyz.com')` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use
cy.ntlm(["etc.domain.com"], "Administrator", "password");

instead of
cy.ntlm(["https://etc.domain.com/dirlisting/notifications"], "Administrator", "password");

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
it('loginpopup', () => {
    cy.ntlm(["https://etc.domain.com/dirlisting/notifications"], "Administrator", "password");
    cy.visit("https://etc.domain.com/dirlisting/notifications");
  })
```

to

```
it('loginpopup', () => {
    cy.ntlm("https://etc.domain.com", "Administrator", "password");
    cy.visit("https://etc.domain.com/dirlisting/notifications");
  })
```